# How to clean unnecesary files or programs on linux (mainly /usr/lib)?

Tags: disk-cleanup, clean-install

[image: Disk Usage]

As you can see my hard drive is getting full, I want to clean some old programs but I want to discover who uses /usr/lib because is quite big ! Thanks

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTE (64 bits)

Comment: Less than 1GB is not big, at all.

Comment: Sorry, I'm saying /usr/lib not /lib

Comment: Most likely with `apt` (to find out which packages you don't need and remove them with it). There's also `dpkg` for you find out what files do the packages hold.

Comment: Please share a view with the content of the `/usr` directory, so that we can see how size is used.